# missing examples for Zend Framework 2 tutorial "Learning Dependency Injection"

Tags: php, dependency-injection, zend-framework2

(After some very (!) useful links to articles about DI and a basic example) In the chapter "[Simplest usage case (2 classes, one consumes the other)](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.1/en/tutorials/quickstart.di.html#simplest-usage-case-2-classes-one-consumes-the-other)" the Zend Framework 2 tutorial "[Learning Dependency Injection](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.1/en/tutorials/quickstart.di.html)" provides an example for **constructor injection**. This one is OK. Then it shows an example of **setter injection**. But it's not complete (the call / usage part of the example is missing). Examples for **interface injection** and **annotation based injection** are missing.

(1) How would look the missing part of the setter injection example? Can someone please moreover write a an (2) interface injection and (3) annotation based injection example with the classes from the tutorial?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 4):

You probably want to look into [Ralph Schindler's Zend\Di examples](https://github.com/ralphschindler/Zend_DI-Examples), which cover all the various `Zend\Di` use cases.

I also [started working on the Zend\Di documentation](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2-documentation/pull/82), but never got to finish it because I was too busy with other stuff (will eventually pick it up again).

Setter injection (enforced):

```php
class Foo 
{
    public $bar;

    public function setBar(Bar $bar)
    {
        $this->bar = $bar;
    }
}

class Bar 
{
}

$di  = new Zend\Di\Di;
$cfg = new Zend\Di\Configuration(array(
    'definition' => array(
        'class' => array(
            'Foo' => array(
                // forcing setBar to be called
                'setBar' => array('required' => true)
            )
        )
    )
)));

$foo = $di->get('Foo');

var_dump($foo->bar); // contains an instance of Bar
```

Setter injection (from given parameters):

```php
class Foo 
{
    public $bar;

    public function setBar($bar)
    {
        $this->bar = $bar;
    }
}

$di     = new Zend\Di\Di;
$config = new Zend\Di\Configuration(array(
    'instance' => array(                
        'Foo' => array(
            // letting Zend\Di find out there's a $bar to inject where possible
            'parameters' => array('bar' => 'baz'),
        )
    )
)));
$config->configure($di);

$foo = $di->get('Foo');

var_dump($foo->bar); // 'baz'
```

Interface injection. `Zend\Di` discovers injection methods from an `*Aware*` interface [as defined in the introspection strategy](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/release-2.1.3/library/Zend/Di/Definition/IntrospectionStrategy.php#L34):

```php
interface BarAwareInterface
{
    public function setBar(Bar $bar);
}

class Foo implements BarAwareInterface
{
    public $bar;

    public function setBar(Bar $bar)
    {
        $this->bar = $bar;
    }
}

class Bar 
{
}


$di  = new Zend\Di\Di;
$foo = $di->get('Foo');

var_dump($foo->bar); // contains an instance of Bar
```

Annotation injection. `Zend\Di` discovers injection methods via annotations:

```php
class Foo 
{
    public $bar;

    /**
     * @Di\Inject()
     */
    public function setBar(Bar $bar)
    {
        $this->bar = $bar;
    }
}

class Bar 
{
}


$di  = new Zend\Di\Di;
$di
    ->definitions()
    ->getIntrospectionStrategy()
    ->setUseAnnotations(true);

$foo = $di->get('Foo');

var_dump($foo->bar); // contains an instance of Bar
```

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer! What I wanted to get is a "completion" of the ZF2 tutorial -- it's why I wrote "examples **with the classes from the tutorial**". So I was already going to edit your examples, in order to adapt them to the tutorial. But the tutorial seems to be not up to date. It uses classes/methods (`getInstanceManager()`, `AggregateDefinition`), that don't exist in the framework (anymore?). It doesn't make sense to complete a tutorial, that contains such errors. It should be corrected first. But for this task I don't have enough know-how yet. Anyway +1 for your examples.

Comment: @automatix not sure about what you just asked me to do... These examples represent the 3 requested injection methods of your question. If you got time to contribute to the docs: please do! As you've seen, `Zend\Di` docs are incomplete because I got stuck.

Comment: I cannot correct the tutorial (know-how problem, s. above :)), but I've opened an [issue](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2-documentation/issues/703) on GitHub.

Comment: @automatix then I'll do it in the next documentation fixing hunt ( http://zend-framework-community.634137.n4.nabble.com/Lets-get-our-docs-sorted-td4659337.html ), but I still don't get what is missing from the answer :)

Comment: The examples as such are absolutely great! What I was meaning is, that it's not possible to _complete_ / _continue_ the tutorial with them, just to "copy&paste" them into the tutorial. One needs e.g. first to map the Foos and Bars onto the As and Bs of the tutorial. It's a minor thing, but it can be a small additional barrier for beginners and it would be didactically better to do the examples **embeddable** (yeah, I've finally found the precise word!) into the tutorial. Hart to explain, but I think, you'll understand, what I'm meaning, if/when you will be adding the examples to the tutorial.